# Static member object initialization failure

Tags: c++

I have a static library with the following code:

h file:

```
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo()
   {
       a = 4;
   }

   int a;
};


class Bar
{
public:
    static const Foo foo;
};
```

cpp file:

```
const Bar::foo = Foo();
```

My problem is that Bar::foo does not get initialized with a=4 until some time *after* main(). Before then a=0. I'm trying to access Bar::foo from a DLL which statically links to the library above. And my application links to that DLL but does not access Bar::foo directly. I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Does anyone know what could be going on?

Answer (score 7):

> $3.6.2/2- "Variables with static
>   storage duration (3.7.1) or thread
>   storage duration (3.7.2) **shall be
>   zero-initialized (8.5) before any
>   other initialization takes place."**

That explains why you get that value of 0

> $3.6.2/4- "It is
>   implementation-defined whether the
>   dynamic initialization of a non-local
>   variable with static storage duration
>   is done before the first statement of
>   main. **If the initialization is
>   deferred to some point in time after
>   the first statement of main, it shall
>   occur before the first use of any
>   function or variable defined in the
>   same translation unit as the variable
>   to be initialized.**"

So what you are trying to do leads to undefined behavior as you are attempting to access a variable with static storage duration which has not yet been initialized as no code in that translation unit has been used as yet.

Comment: Microsoft's implementation-defined behavior for the described scenario is that the initialization will have occurred before the DllMain()'s 'process attach' call is made.

Comment: @Michael Burr: Oh Ok. That is a good piece of information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Where and when exactly are you accessing `Bar::foo`?  If it's statically linked into the DLL, then it should be initialized before `DllMain()`'s 'process attach' is called.

Are you setting a different entry point for the DLL than the default of `_DllMainCRTStartup`?

Comment: I'm not using _DllMainCRTStartup; the DLL has no entry point per se, it's just a bunch of abstract class interfaces and implementations with a global extern C function to create the root class instance. It's done this way to be binary compatible. Do I need to define an entry point?

Comment: `_DlMainCRTStartup` is part of the runtime library - you'll get it by default unless you do something specifically to override it.

Comment: @Matthew - how is code in the DLL executing before `main()`?  There must be something in `DllMain()`, an alternate DLL entry point, or some static init in your .exe must be calling into the DLL.

Comment: There's no code executing in the DLL before main(). In the example I posted above the Foo constructor should be executing before main() as it's static, but it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you define a static method in bar which returns a reference to Foo, and in that static method, have a static instance of Foo, such that when it's first called (irrespective of where), it will get correctly initialised?

```
class Bar
{
  public:
    static Foo& foo()
    {
      static Foo inst;
      return inst;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What code is noticing that `Bar::foo` isn't initialized yet? If it's another bit of static initialization in the DLL then you're probably running into C++'s static initialization order problem:

- from the C++ FAQ: [What's the "static initialization order fiasco"?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14)